# Loop throught 2 array and use onclick for items

Tags: javascript

i have a template with  repeating blocks , the idia is to toggle closet  .products_block every time when i click on .id_name , how can i do it ? For instance if i will click on third .id_name i want to toggle only third .products_block.

i catch the elements

```
const elem  = document.getElementsByClassName('id_name');
const prod  = document.getElementsByClassName('products_block');
```

make an arrays

```
const elemArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(elem)
const prodArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(prod)

<div class="id_name">
     <p>onlcik</p>
     <div class="products_block">
         <p>show</p>
     </div>
 </div>

<div class="id_name">
     <p>onlcik</p>
     <div class="products_block">
         <p>show</p>
     </div>
 </div>

....
```

Comment: In what way do you want to 'toggle' it? Make it visible or what?

Comment: yep , jus switch between display : none , block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for ? http://jsfiddle.net/mp2xL1uc/

```
var idArr = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('id_name'));

idArr.forEach(idEl => {
  Array.from(idEl.children)[0].addEventListener('click', function(e){
    if(Array.from(idEl.children)[1].style.display === 'none'){
      Array.from(idEl.children)[1].style.display = 'block';
    }
    else{
      Array.from(idEl.children)[1].style.display = 'none';
    }
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="id_name">
     <p>onlcik</p>
     <div class="products_block" style="display: none;">
         <p>show</p>
     </div>
 </div>

<div class="id_name">
     <p>onlcik</p>
     <div class="products_block" style="display: none;">
         <p>show</p>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var links = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('id_name'));

// hide a specific element
var hideProduct = (elem) => { elem.style.display = 'none'; }

// click handler 
var onClik = (index, event) => {
  // make clicked element products visible
  links[index].children.item(1).style.display = 'block';
  
  // filter rest of the sections and hide'em
  let filtered = links.filter((item) => item != links[index]);
  filtered.forEach((v,i) => hideProduct(v.children.item(1)))
};


// add click handler to clickables as suggested
links.forEach((el, index) => {
  Array.from(el.children)[0].addEventListener('click', (e) => onClik(index, e));
});
```

```css
.id_name > p:first-child { color: blue; text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer;}
```

```html
<div class="id_name">
     <p>onlcik</p>
     <div class="products_block">
         <p>show 1</p>
     </div>
 </div>

<div class="id_name">
     <p>onlcik</p>
     <div class="products_block">
         <p>show 2</p>
     </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="id_name">
     <p>onlcik</p>
     <div class="products_block">
         <p>show 3</p>
     </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="id_name">
     <p>onlcik</p>
     <div class="products_block">
         <p>show 4</p>
     </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="id_name">
     <p>onlcik</p>
     <div class="products_block">
         <p>show 5</p>
     </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="id_name">
     <p>onlcik</p>
     <div class="products_block">
         <p>show 6</p>
     </div>
 </div>
```

If you want to display one and hide all on default just add `style = 'display:none'` to add `product_block` items except the one you want to display as default.